# what is diffrence using var or this inside function in JS?

Tags: javascript

I wonder is there any diffrence, in below codes:

```
function x(){
   var a = 1;
}
```

and:

```
function x(){
   this.a = 1;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first creates a locally-scoped variable, which will not be retained after the function exits (unless by a closure created inside the function).

The second creates an expando property on the `this` object, possibly overwriting any previous value for that property.

Comment: … and the `this` object depends on how the function is called. By default you will be doing `x()` which is the same as `window.x()` so `this` is `window`. If you were to do `new x()` then `this` would be the new instance of the x 'class'.

Comment: And if you use `x.call(...)` or `x.apply(...)` you can have `this` be whatever object you want. You could also do something like `foo.x = x; foo.x();`. And passing `x` to functions like `Array.filter` will result in differing values for `this` too.

Answer (score 0):

scope of variable will be  changed.. the var inside function will be exist only when that function will called

**[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500431/javascript-variable-scope)**

Answer (score -1):

The scope.

this.a will check for a window property a, and makes it global

```
function x(){
   this.a = 1;
}
```

is equal to

```
var instantance_a;
function x(){
   instantance_a = 1;
}
```

or rather a global property lik

`window.a`